# Python: Using two csv's get the minimum square root (or find minimum distance))

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have 2 csv files -

CSV A-

```
Col1   Col2         Col3        Col4         Col5        Col6
23      XY      -2852059.23, 5257582.12, -2205236.45      AA
25      AB      -2852159.23, 5257577.12, -2205245.43      BB
31      CF      -2852259.23, 5257569.12, -2205240.46      CC 
35      CV      -2852359.23, 5257565.12, -2205246.47      DD
76      FH      -2852459.23, 5257573.12, -2205241.47      EE
34      TY      -2852559.23, 5257564.12, -2205244.56      FF
```

CSV B-

```
Col1       Col2      Col3      Col4
75      -28059.23, 52582.12, -25236.45
23      -28159.23, 52577.12, -25245.43
34      -28259.23, 52569.12, -25240.46
56      -28359.23, 52565.12, -25246.47
67      -28459.23, 52573.12, -25241.47
34      -28559.23, 52564.12, -25244.56
```

I am trying to find the minimum square root or minimum distance using distance formula(√[(x₂ - x₁)² + (y₂ - y₁)²+ (z₂ - z₁)²] ). For example -
First row of A.csv should be subtracted to all rows with B.csv one by one and calculate the square root and then take the minimum square root from all square roots. Same needs to be done for all other rows in A.csv.

I am using the below code to achieve the same, it's working as expected. But it is taking so much time to finish.

```
df1['min_sqrt'] = np.sqrt((df2['Col2'].apply(lambda x: (x-df1['Col3'])**2))+(df2['Col3'].apply(lambda x: (x-df1['Col4'])**2))+(df2['Col4'].apply(lambda x: (x-df1['Col5'])**2))).min()
```

Looking for an improved/quicker solution.
Thank you in advance.

Tried with merge function as well. Below is the code -

```
out = (
    df1.merge(df2, how="cross")
       .assign(x= lambda df: (df['Col2'] - df['Col3']).pow(2),
               y= lambda df: (df['Col3'] - df['Col4']).pow(2),
               z= lambda df: (df['Col4'] - df['Col5']).pow(2),
               distance= lambda df: np.sqrt(df.x + df.y + df.z))
       .groupby(["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6"], sort=False, axis=0).agg(min_sqrt=("distance", "min"))
                
   )
```

Working fine with small set of data but giving memory error with huge data file.
**MemoryError: Unable to allocate 23.2 GiB for an array with shape (31, 100453255) and data type float64**

Can someone please help me with this ? struggling to find the better solution as it is taking too much time to process.