# Postgres find duplicates using multiple columns and delete one row based on column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a table below with sample data.

```
|  id  | type| cycle|    datetimestamp    |  status1  |  status2  |
|:----:|:---:|:----:|:-------------------:|:---------:|:---------:|
| 27   | AN  |  123 | 2022-12-28 04:12:31 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 27   | AR  |  124 | 2022-12-28 04:12:31 | Normal A  | Normal A  |<--Delete
| 19   | AN  |  125 | 2022-12-28 05:24:30 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 19   | AR  |  126 | 2022-12-28 06:18:20 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 19   | AR  |  234 | 2022-12-28 07:22:20 | Normal A  | Normal A  |<--Delete
| 19   | AN  |  235 | 2022-12-28 07:22:20 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 20   | AR  |  236 | 2022-12-28 08:25:49 | Normal A  | Normal A  |<--Delete
| 20   | AN  |  237 | 2022-12-28 08:25:49 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 19   | AR  |  129 | 2022-12-28 09:08:19 | Normal A  | Normal A  |<--Delete
| 19   | AN  |  127 | 2022-12-28 09:08:19 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 19   | AR  |  238 | 2022-12-28 10:04:31 | Normal A  | Normal A  |<--Delete
| 19   | AN  |  230 | 2022-12-28 10:04:31 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 22   | AN  |  239 | 2022-12-28 11:04:58 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 22   | AR  |  256 | 2022-12-28 11:04:58 | Normal A  | Normal A  |<--Delete
```

I want to find out the duplicates using columns(id, type, datetimestamp, status1, status2)
and delete the duplicate row having column type='AR'(keep the type='AN'). Expecting below output -

```
|  id  | type| cycle|    datetimestamp    |  status1  |  status2  |
|:----:|:---:|:----:|:-------------------:|:---------:|:---------:|
| 27   | AN  |  123 | 2022-12-28 04:12:31 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 19   | AN  |  125 | 2022-12-28 05:24:30 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 19   | AR  |  126 | 2022-12-28 06:18:20 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 19   | AN  |  235 | 2022-12-28 07:22:20 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 20   | AN  |  237 | 2022-12-28 08:25:49 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 19   | AN  |  127 | 2022-12-28 09:08:19 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 19   | AN  |  230 | 2022-12-28 10:04:31 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
| 22   | AN  |  239 | 2022-12-28 11:04:58 | Normal A  | Normal A  |
```

But my query is returning having type='AN' not 'AR'.

```
select * from test_data e
where exists
 ( select * from test_data e2 
   where e.datetimestamp=e2.datetimestamp and e.id=e2.id 
     and e.status1=e2.status1 
     and e.status2=e2.status2 
     and e.type='AN' and e2.type='AR') order by e.datetimestamp asc;
```

Setup table queries:

```
~~~pgsql
CREATE TABLE test_data (
 id character varying(2) NOT NULL,
 type character varying(2),
 cycle integer,
 datetimestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
 status1 character varying(10),
 status2 character varying(10),
 PRIMARY KEY(id, cycle, datetimestamp)
);

INSERT INTO test_data VALUES
  (27, 'AN', 123, '2022-12-28 04:12:31', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (27, 'AR', 124, '2022-12-28 04:12:31', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (19, 'AN', 125, '2022-12-28 05:24:30', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (19, 'AR', 126, '2022-12-28 06:18:20', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (19, 'AR', 234, '2022-12-28 07:22:20', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (19, 'AN', 235, '2022-12-28 07:22:20', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (20, 'AR', 236, '2022-12-28 08:25:49', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (20, 'AN', 237, '2022-12-28 08:25:49', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (19, 'AR', 129, '2022-12-28 09:08:19', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (19, 'AN', 127, '2022-12-28 09:08:19', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (19, 'AR', 238, '2022-12-28 10:04:31', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (19, 'AN', 230, '2022-12-28 10:04:31', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (22, 'AN', 239, '2022-12-28 11:04:58', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
, (22, 'AR', 256, '2022-12-28 11:04:58', 'Normal A', 'Normal A')
;
~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
DELETE FROM test_data a
USING test_data b
WHERE a.id = b.id
  AND a.type = 'AN'
  AND b.type = 'AR'
  AND a.datetimestamp = b.datetimestamp
  AND a.status1 = b.status2
  AND a.status2 = b.status2
```

test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2OSRBb4f)

Comment: Hi @Edouard, thank you for the reply. It's working as expected. How can we achieve If I want to delete exact match or nearby (a.datetimestamp - b.datetimestamp <= 3 secs) match. Let's say If we increased 17th line in dbfiddle by 2 secs and still want to delete the 16th line and keep 17th line?

Comment: just replace `AND a.datetimestamp = b.datetimestamp` by `AND a.datetimestamp - b.datetimestamp BETWEEN interval '-3 seconds' AND interval '3 seconds'`

Comment: I am looking for another solution in Python Panda's, please help me if you or any of your contact know's python - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440137/python-using-two-csvs-get-the-minimum-square-root-or-find-minimum-distance.

Answer (score 1):

`exists` looks like a good approach. Starting from your query, I just fixed the conditions on `type` (we want to delete "AR" record based on the presence of "AN") ; I also rewrote the multiple equalities to tuple equality - but that's just syntactic sugar:

```
delete 
from test_data e1
where type = 'AR' and exists (
    select 1 
    from test_data e2
    where (e2.datetimestamp, e2.id, e2.status1, e2.status2, e2.type) 
        = (e1.datetimestamp, e1.id, e1.status1, e1.status2, 'AN')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list the deleted row by this query:

```
ALTER TABLE test_data ADD COLUMN test_data_id serial;

SELECT t.test_data_id 
FROM test_data t
JOIN (
        SELECT array_agg(test_data_id) as arr from test_data GROUP BY id, datetimestamp, status1, status2 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as dup
    ON t.test_data_id = ANY(dup.arr)
WHERE t.type = 'AR'
```

So the delete query will be:

```
DELETE FROM test_data 
WHERE test_data_id IN (
        select t.test_data_id 
        from test_data t
        JOIN (
                select array_agg(test_data_id) as arr from test_data GROUP BY id, datetimestamp, status1, status2 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            ) as dup ON t.test_data_id = ANY(dup.arr)
        WHERE t.type = 'AR'
)
```

A little explain: My solution is you create a new unique column and take it as a primary key. Then you can filter the duplicate row and remove it with the type 'AR'.

p/s: if you don't allow to add 1 more column you can use ctid column instead but I don't refer this solution.

Hopefully, it will help you.